# ERROR AL REGISTRARSE

Tags: php, mysql, crud

Buenas noches tengo una duda,
al realizar la carga de información de mi formulario me sale el error "usuario no registrado", es el mismo alert que yo codifico pero ya busque y nada.  No registra nada, no aplica el insert con la variable necesit que lo realiza, tambien al logearme me dice usuario o contraseñas incorrectos

aca el php

```
<?php
include ("conexion.php");

if(isset($_POST["registrar"])){
    $nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['nombre']);
    $correo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['correo']);
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['user']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['pass']);
    $password_encriptada = sha1($password);
    $sqluser ="SELECT idusuarios FROM usuarios where usuario ='$usuario'";

    $resultadouser=$conexion->query($sqluser);

    $filas= $resultadouser->num_rows;
    if($filas > 0){
        echo "<script>
        alert ('El usuario ya existe');
        window.location ='index.php';
        </script>";
    }else{
        $sqlusuario="INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,correo,usuario,password) VALUES ('$nombre', '$correo','$usuario','$password_encriptada')";
       if($resultadousuario > 0 ){
        echo "<script>
        alert ('registro exitoso');
        window.location ='index.php';
        </script>";
       }else {
        echo "<script>
        alert ('error al registrarse');
        window.location = 'index.php';
        </script>";
       }
    }





}
```

y aca el form que recibe los parametros
pero me sale error no se registro el usuario y no lo guarda en mysql phpmyadmin
y las variables se supone que estan ejecutandose no se si tenga que ver con los privilegios de phpmyadmin

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="POST" >
            <fieldset>
                        <label class="block clearfix">
                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre Completo"  required />
                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-users"></i>
                    </span>
                </label>

                <label class="block clearfix">
                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="correo" placeholder="Email"  required />
                                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-envelope"></i>
                    </span>
                </label>
                    <label class="block clearfix">
                        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="Usuario"  required />
                                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-user"></i>
                        </span>
                </label>
                <label class="block clearfix">
                                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Password"  required />
                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-lock"></i>
                    </span>
                </label>

                <label class="block clearfix">
                    <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passr" placeholder="Repetir password" />
                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-retweet"></i>
                                    </span>
                </label>

                <label class="block">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="ace" />
                        <span class="lbl">
                        Acepto los
                        <a href="#">Terminos de Uso</a>
                        </span>
                </label>
                <div class="space-24"></div>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <button type="reset" class="width-30 pull-left btn btn-sm">
                        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-refresh"></i>
                            <span class="bigger-110">Reset</span>
                    </button>

                    <button type="submit" name="registrar"   class="width-65 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-success">
                        <span class="bigger-110">Registrar</span>
                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-arrow-right icon-on-right"></i>
                    </button>
                     </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Comment: Hola, cuando encriptas la clave no estaras sobrepasando el tamaño del campo?

Comment: lo tengo a 45 varhcra

Comment: y cuando queda encriptado? se suele hacer una cadena muy larga de caracteres cuando encriptas

Comment: no encripta nada no lo guarda me arroja mi alert de no se registro usuario

Comment: ok, creo que debes revisar que los nombres de tablas y campos correspondan, que el tamaño de los campos también correspondan y verifica que los datos que vos estas rellenando lleguen al insert, quizas en tu tabla es not null en el campo contraseña y llega null.

Comment: si llega null pero siempre lo relleno

Comment: algo pasa en el medio que no estamos viendo en el codigo que muestras, que lo hace llegar null, pero puede ser null sin problemas si en tu base de datos lo permites.

Comment: tengo idusuarios

Comment: nombre, correo,usuario,password